Android, How to call java function from Rust?
I have a Rust library that I compile as a static library for Android. I already have normal calls working. However, I would like to use the Keystore classes to securely store data from Rust using the Android APIs.
I took this example used by the app_dirs2 library, to load the jni env and then try to call some java functions using the ndk_context library:
use log::info;

pub fn try_jni_call() -> Result<(), jni::errors::Error> {
    info!("mark0!");
    let android_context = ndk_context::android_context();
    info!("mark1!");
    let vm = unsafe { jni::JavaVM::from_raw(android_context.vm().cast()) }?;
    info!("mark2!");
    let mut env = vm.attach_current_thread()?;
    info!("mark3!");
    // let context = unsafe { jni::objects::JObject::from_raw(android_context.context().cast()) };

    // let class = env.find_class("java/lang/String")?;
    let string = env.new_string("Hello, world!")?;
    info!("mark4!");
    let length = env.call_method(string, "length", "()I", &[])?;
    info!("mark5!");

    info!("{:?}", length);
    Ok(())
}

Everything compiles, however when I try to call my function the Android app crashes with a memory error and no useful info:
2024-05-31 13:24:52.499  8994-9091  libc                    com.trnslcd                          A  Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 9091 (mqt_v_js), pid 8994 (com.trnslcd)
2024-05-31 13:24:52.577  8994-9044  EGL_emulation           com.trnslcd                          D  app_time_stats: avg=50.52ms min=11.14ms max=699.97ms count=20
2024-05-31 13:24:52.737  9141-9141  DEBUG                   pid-9141                             A  Cmdline: com.trnslcd
2024-05-31 13:24:52.737  9141-9141  DEBUG                   pid-9141                             A  pid: 8994, tid: 9091, name: mqt_v_js  >>> com.trnslcd <<<
2024-05-31 13:24:52.738  9141-9141  DEBUG                   pid-9141                             A        #01 pc 0000000001936cac  /data/app/~~4UgfCXkCPin4OiqcJRwykA==/com.trnslcd-eoo4UZzkTFGO39QK-HUV9Q==/base.apk!libappmodules.so (offset 0xbe3b000) (std::sys::pal::unix::abort_internal::h22ff110bbc1699b8+4) (BuildId: 7f37ce511bd565e6a02786c127a61fd93c3d6a57)
2024-05-31 13:24:52.738  9141-9141  DEBUG                   pid-9141                             A        #02 pc 000000000192cb8c  /data/app/~~4UgfCXkCPin4OiqcJRwykA==/com.trnslcd-eoo4UZzkTFGO39QK-HUV9Q==/base.apk!libappmodules.so (offset 0xbe3b000) (__rust_drop_panic+116) (BuildId: 7f37ce511bd565e6a02786c127a61fd93c3d6a57)
2024-05-31 13:24:52.738  9141-9141  DEBUG                   pid-9141                             A        #03 pc 000000000193c104  /data/app/~~4UgfCXkCPin4OiqcJRwykA==/com.trnslcd-eoo4UZzkTFGO39QK-HUV9Q==/base.apk!libappmodules.so (offset 0xbe3b000) (BuildId: 7f37ce511bd565e6a02786c127a61fd93c3d6a57)
2024-05-31 13:24:52.738  9141-9141  DEBUG                   pid-9141                             A        #04 pc 00000000000b6c00  /data/app/~~4UgfCXkCPin4OiqcJRwykA==/com.trnslcd-eoo4UZzkTFGO39QK-HUV9Q==/base.apk!libc++_shared.so (offset 0x1629000) (__cxa_end_catch+100) (BuildId: 982d68842b3bd6a164609be09a533324b1f28526)
2024-05-31 13:24:52.738  9141-9141  DEBUG                   pid-9141                             A        #05 pc 00000000000b895c  /data/app/~~4UgfCXkCPin4OiqcJRwykA==/com.trnslcd-eoo4UZzkTFGO39QK-HUV9Q==/base.apk!libhermes.so (offset 0x40d8000) (BuildId: 683476cc848a599ba6ecd7670dc2917c0466b6a8)
2024-05-31 13:24:52.738  9141-9141  DEBUG                   pid-9141                             A        #06 pc 00000000001150c4  /data/app/~~4UgfCXkCPin4OiqcJRwykA==/com.trnslcd-eoo4UZzkTFGO39QK-HUV9Q==/base.apk!libhermes.so (offset 0x40d8000) (BuildId: 683476cc848a599ba6ecd7670dc2917c0466b6a8)
2024-05-31 13:24:52.738  9141-9141  DEBUG                   pid-9141                             A        #07 pc 00000000001342cc  /data/app/~~4UgfCXkCPin4OiqcJRwykA==/com.trnslcd-eoo4UZzkTFGO39QK-HUV9Q==/base.apk!libhermes.so (offset 0x40d8000) (BuildId: 683476cc848a599ba6ecd7670dc2917c0466b6a8)
2024-05-31 13:24:52.738  9141-9141  DEBUG                   pid-9141                             A        #08 pc 0000000000133800  /data/app/~~4UgfCXkCPin4OiqcJRwykA==/com.trnslcd-eoo4UZzkTFGO39QK-HUV9Q==/base.apk!libhermes.so (offset 0x40d8000) (BuildId: 683476cc848a599ba6ecd7670dc2917c0466b6a8)
2024-05-31 13:24:52.739  9141-9141  DEBUG                   pid-9141                             A        #09 pc 00000000001153bc  /data/app/~~4UgfCXkCPin4OiqcJRwykA==/com.trnslcd-eoo4UZzkTFGO39QK-HUV9Q==/base.apk!libhermes.so (offset 0x40d8000) (BuildId: 683476cc848a599ba6ecd7670dc2917c0466b6a8)
2024-05-31 13:24:52.739  9141-9141  DEBUG                   pid-9141                             A        #10 pc 0000000000113de0  /data/app/~~4UgfCXkCPin4OiqcJRwykA==/com.trnslcd-eoo4UZzkTFGO39QK-HUV9Q==/base.apk!libhermes.so (offset 0x40d8000) (BuildId: 683476cc848a599ba6ecd7670dc2917c0466b6a8)
2024-05-31 13:24:52.739  9141-9141  DEBUG                   pid-9141                             A        #11 pc 00000000001dc230  /data/app/~~4UgfCXkCPin4OiqcJRwykA==/com.trnslcd-eoo4UZzkTFGO39QK-HUV9Q==/base.apk!libhermes.so (offset 0x40d8000) (BuildId: 683476cc848a599ba6ecd7670dc2917c0466b6a8)
2024-05-31 13:24:52.739  9141-9141  DEBUG                   pid-9141                             A        #12 pc 00000000001150c4  /data/app/~~4UgfCXkCPin4OiqcJRwykA==/com.trnslcd-eoo4UZzkTFGO39QK-HUV9Q==/base.apk!libhermes.so (offset 0x40d8000) (BuildId: 683476cc848a599ba6ecd7670dc2917c0466b6a8)
2024-05-31 13:24:52.739  9141-9141  DEBUG                   pid-9141                             A        #13 pc 00000000001342cc  /data/app/~~4UgfCXkCPin4OiqcJRwykA==/com.trnslcd-eoo4UZzkTFGO39QK-HUV9Q==/base.apk!libhermes.so (offset 0x40d8000) (BuildId: 683476cc848a599ba6ecd7670dc2917c0466b6a8)
2024-05-31 13:24:52.739  9141-9141  DEBUG                   pid-9141                             A        #14 pc 0000000000133800  /data/app/~~4UgfCXkCPin4OiqcJRwykA==/com.trnslcd-eoo4UZzkTFGO39QK-HUV9Q==/base.apk!libhermes.so (offset 0x40d8000) (BuildId: 683476cc848a599ba6ecd7670dc2917c0466b6a8)
2024-05-31 13:24:52.739  9141-9141  DEBUG                   pid-9141                             A        #15 pc 00000000001153bc  /data/app/~~4UgfCXkCPin4OiqcJRwykA==/com.trnslcd-eoo4UZzkTFGO39QK-HUV9Q==/base.apk!libhermes.so (offset 0x40d8000) (BuildId: 683476cc848a599ba6ecd7670dc2917c0466b6a8)
2024-05-31 13:24:52.739  9141-9141  DEBUG                   pid-9141                             A        #16 pc 0000000000113de0  /data/app/~~4UgfCXkCPin4OiqcJRwykA==/com.trnslcd-eoo4UZzkTFGO39QK-HUV9Q==/base.apk!libhermes.so (offset 0x40d8000) (BuildId: 683476cc848a599ba6ecd7670dc2917c0466b6a8)
2024-05-31 13:24:52.739  9141-9141  DEBUG                   pid-9141                             A        #17 pc 00000000001dc230  /data/app/~~4UgfCXkCPin4OiqcJRwykA==/com.trnslcd-eoo4UZzkTFGO39QK-HUV9Q==/base.apk!libhermes.so (offset 0x40d8000) (BuildId: 683476cc848a599ba6ecd7670dc2917c0466b6a8)
2024-05-31 13:24:52.739  9141-9141  DEBUG                   pid-9141                             A        #18 pc 00000000001150c4  /data/app/~~4UgfCXkCPin4OiqcJRwykA==/com.trnslcd-eoo4UZzkTFGO39QK-HUV9Q==/base.apk!libhermes.so (offset 0x40d8000) (BuildId: 683476cc848a599ba6ecd7670dc2917c0466b6a8)
2024-05-31 13:24:52.739  9141-9141  DEBUG                   pid-9141                             A        #19 pc 00000000001342cc  /data/app/~~4UgfCXkCPin4OiqcJRwykA==/com.trnslcd-eoo4UZzkTFGO39QK-HUV9Q==/base.apk!libhermes.so (offset 0x40d8000) (BuildId: 683476cc848a599ba6ecd7670dc2917c0466b6a8)
2024-05-31 13:24:52.739  9141-9141  DEBUG                   pid-9141                             A        #20 pc 0000000000133800  /data/app/~~4UgfCXkCPin4OiqcJRwykA==/com.trnslcd-eoo4UZzkTFGO39QK-HUV9Q==/base.apk!libhermes.so (offset 0x40d8000) (BuildId: 683476cc848a599ba6ecd7670dc2917c0466b6a8)
2024-05-31 13:24:52.739  9141-9141  DEBUG                   pid-9141                             A        #21 pc 00000000001153bc  /data/app/~~4UgfCXkCPin4OiqcJRwykA==/com.trnslcd-eoo4UZzkTFGO39QK-HUV9Q==/base.apk!libhermes.so (offset 0x40d8000) (BuildId: 683476cc848a599ba6ecd7670dc2917c0466b6a8)
2024-05-31 13:24:52.739  9141-9141  DEBUG                   pid-9141                             A        #22 pc 0000000000113de0  /data/app/~~4UgfCXkCPin4OiqcJRwykA==/com.trnslcd-eoo4UZzkTFGO39QK-HUV9Q==/base.apk!libhermes.so (offset 0x40d8000) (BuildId: 683476cc848a599ba6ecd7670dc2917c0466b6a8)
2024-05-31 13:24:52.739  9141-9141  DEBUG                   pid-9141                             A        #23 pc 00000000001dc230  /data/app/~~4UgfCXkCPin4OiqcJRwykA==/com.trnslcd-eoo4UZzkTFGO39QK-HUV9Q==/base.apk!libhermes.so (offset 0x40d8000) (BuildId: 683476cc848a599ba6ecd7670dc2917c0466b6a8)
2024-05-31 13:24:52.739  9141-9141  DEBUG                   pid-9141                             A        #24 pc 00000000001150c4  /data/app/~~4UgfCXkCPin4OiqcJRwykA==/com.trnslcd-eoo4UZzkTFGO39QK-HUV9Q==/base.apk!libhermes.so (offset 0x40d8000) (BuildId: 683476cc848a599ba6ecd7670dc2917c0466b6a8)
2024-05-31 13:24:52.739  9141-9141  DEBUG                   pid-9141                             A        #25 pc 00000000001342cc  /data/app/~~4UgfCXkCPin4OiqcJRwykA==/com.trnslcd-eoo4UZzkTFGO39QK-HUV9Q==/base.apk!libhermes.so (offset 0x40d8000) (BuildId: 683476cc848a599ba6ecd7670dc2917c0466b6a8)
2024-05-31 13:24:52.739  9141-9141  DEBUG                   pid-9141                             A        #26 pc 0000000000133800  /data/app/~~4UgfCXkCPin4OiqcJRwykA==/com.trnslcd-eoo4UZzkTFGO39QK-HUV9Q==/base.apk!libhermes.so (offset 0x40d8000) (BuildId: 683476cc848a599ba6ecd7670dc2917c0466b6a8)
2024-05-31 13:24:52.739  9141-9141  DEBUG                   pid-9141                             A        #27 pc 00000000001153bc  /data/app/~~4UgfCXkCPin4OiqcJRwykA==/com.trnslcd-eoo4UZzkTFGO39QK-HUV9Q==/base.apk!libhermes.so (offset 0x40d8000) (BuildId: 683476cc848a599ba6ecd7670dc2917c0466b6a8)
2024-05-31 13:24:52.739  9141-9141  DEBUG                   pid-9141                             A        #28 pc 0000000000113734  /data/app/~~4UgfCXkCPin4OiqcJRwykA==/com.trnslcd-eoo4UZzkTFGO39QK-HUV9Q==/base.apk!libhermes.so (offset 0x40d8000) (BuildId: 683476cc848a599ba6ecd7670dc2917c0466b6a8)
2024-05-31 13:24:52.739  9141-9141  DEBUG                   pid-9141                             A        #29 pc 00000000001953c4  /data/app/~~4UgfCXkCPin4OiqcJRwykA==/com.trnslcd-eoo4UZzkTFGO39QK-HUV9Q==/base.apk!libhermes.so (offset 0x40d8000) (BuildId: 683476cc848a599ba6ecd7670dc2917c0466b6a8)
2024-05-31 13:24:52.739  9141-9141  DEBUG                   pid-9141                             A        #30 pc 00000000001150c4  /data/app/~~4UgfCXkCPin4OiqcJRwykA==/com.trnslcd-eoo4UZzkTFGO39QK-HUV9Q==/base.apk!libhermes.so (offset 0x40d8000) (BuildId: 683476cc848a599ba6ecd7670dc2917c0466b6a8)
2024-05-31 13:24:52.739  9141-9141  DEBUG                   pid-9141                             A        #31 pc 00000000001342cc  /data/app/~~4UgfCXkCPin4OiqcJRwykA==/com.trnslcd-eoo4UZzkTFGO39QK-HUV9Q==/base.apk!libhermes.so (offset 0x40d8000) (BuildId: 683476cc848a599ba6ecd7670dc2917c0466b6a8)
2024-05-31 13:24:52.741  9141-9141  DEBUG                   pid-9141                             A        #32 pc 0000000000133800  /data/app/~~4UgfCXkCPin4OiqcJRwykA==/com.trnslcd-eoo4UZzkTFGO39QK-HUV9Q==/base.apk!libhermes.so (offset 0x40d8000) (BuildId: 683476cc848a599ba6ecd7670dc2917c0466b6a8)
2024-05-31 13:24:52.741  9141-9141  DEBUG                   pid-9141                             A        #33 pc 00000000001153bc  /data/app/~~4UgfCXkCPin4OiqcJRwykA==/com.trnslcd-eoo4UZzkTFGO39QK-HUV9Q==/base.apk!libhermes.so (offset 0x40d8000) (BuildId: 683476cc848a599ba6ecd7670dc2917c0466b6a8)
2024-05-31 13:24:52.741  9141-9141  DEBUG                   pid-9141                             A        #34 pc 00000000000b1170  /data/app/~~4UgfCXkCPin4OiqcJRwykA==/com.trnslcd-eoo4UZzkTFGO39QK-HUV9Q==/base.apk!libhermes.so (offset 0x40d8000) (BuildId: 683476cc848a599ba6ecd7670dc2917c0466b6a8)
2024-05-31 13:24:52.741  9141-9141  DEBUG                   pid-9141                             A        #35 pc 0000000000076000  /data/app/~~4UgfCXkCPin4OiqcJRwykA==/com.trnslcd-eoo4UZzkTFGO39QK-HUV9Q==/base.apk!libhermesinstancejni.so (offset 0xb1ea000) (facebook::jsi::RuntimeDecorator<facebook::jsi::Runtime, facebook::jsi::Runtime>::call(facebook::jsi::Function const&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)+72) (BuildId: 6a6e92fac84edb13)
2024-05-31 13:24:52.741  9141-9141  DEBUG                   pid-9141                             A        #36 pc 0000000000599870  /data/app/~~4UgfCXkCPin4OiqcJRwykA==/com.trnslcd-eoo4UZzkTFGO39QK-HUV9Q==/base.apk!libfabricjni.so (offset 0x2dec000) (facebook::jsi::Function::call(facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long) const+108) (BuildId: 060488353eccc086)
2024-05-31 13:24:52.741  9141-9141  DEBUG                   pid-9141                             A        #37 pc 00000000005997bc  /data/app/~~4UgfCXkCPin4OiqcJRwykA==/com.trnslcd-eoo4UZzkTFGO39QK-HUV9Q==/base.apk!libfabricjni.so (offset 0x2dec000) (facebook::jsi::Function::call(facebook::jsi::Runtime&, std::initializer_list<facebook::jsi::Value>) const+116) (BuildId: 060488353eccc086)
2024-05-31 13:24:52.741  9141-9141  DEBUG                   pid-9141                             A        #38 pc 000000000065f9f4  /data/app/~~4UgfCXkCPin4OiqcJRwykA==/com.trnslcd-eoo4UZzkTFGO39QK-HUV9Q==/base.apk!libfabricjni.so (offset 0x2dec000) (facebook::jsi::Value facebook::jsi::Function::call<facebook::jsi::Value, facebook::jsi::String, facebook::jsi::Value>(facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value&&, facebook::jsi::String&&, facebook::jsi::Value&&) const+252) (BuildId: 060488353eccc086)
2024-05-31 13:24:52.741  9141-9141  DEBUG                   pid-9141                             A        #39 pc 000000000065f50c  /data/app/~~4UgfCXkCPin4OiqcJRwykA==/com.trnslcd-eoo4UZzkTFGO39QK-HUV9Q==/base.apk!libfabricjni.so (offset 0x2dec000) (facebook::react::UIManagerBinding::dispatchEventToJS(facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::react::EventTarget const*, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> > const&, facebook::react::ReactEventPriority, facebook::react::EventPayload const&) const+452) (BuildId: 060488353eccc086)

As extra context, I'm not calling this function from a pure Java method itself, but rather from a C++ function exposed to JavaScript with React-Native. Maybe that's the reason of the crash, but I cannot say atm.
Has anyone ran Rust code that just invokes the JVM and tries to call a Java method on it's own?
Thanks a lot for the help!

Does this answer your question? https://stacoverflow.com/questions/56821728/how-can-i-invoke-a-java-method-from-rust-via-jni

At the top of the stack is a rust panic! call. Run your code under a debugger to catch it, or at least inspect the panic reason.

@cafce25 yeah, that's pretty much the same code I have and the crash is the same. Even when I modify it to use only the jsi crate.

@Botje the problem is that the library is compiled to static and I don't know how to attach the LLVM debugger inside the Android process to get stack traces.

That's why Android Studio has this handy "Debug" button or "Attach to process", if you must. You can also try reproducing this crash in an empty Android JNI project.

Have you ever done this? I don't think it is as simple as you are making it. The code generated by Rust is probably missing the symbols and requires tweaking of the debugger and black magic to get it to play somewhat nicely. At least there is very little info online how to make this work. With the debugger attached I get the same unsymbolicated crash: https://pasteboard.co/60KFwyE6DAOO.png

I have debugged Rust code in JNI, yes. You should recompile your library in debug mode so you can step into the code. Presumably Rust has dumped the stacktrace at panic!-time to stderr but that may be ignored on Android?

Found the problem. It seems I need to call the function from a java context via JNI itself and not from a pure C++ context. Found out by installing app_dirs2 and calling the sample function it crashes with the same error. Thanks for the help!

That sounds like the android_context crate was never initialized with a pointer to a Java VM. I checked the jni crate but there does not seem to be an analogue to JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs. Calling your code from a JNI method is all happiness because that thread by definition already has a JNIEnv set up. Perhaps you can get the raw JNI pointer with jni::sys::JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs and pass that to jni::JavaVM::from_raw

It seems the issue is how I'm calling my Rust function. I'm calling it from a C++ function that is not going through the jni bridge.
I realized the problem by installing the app_dirs2 create and facing the same crash. So I guess I will first have to create a JNI function to trampoline into the Rust code instead of calling it from a C++ context.
